# What do you call a person who is very fussy about weather?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

A person who often says: "It is too sunny" or "It is too cold". What would you call such a person who is very fussy about weather?

Sample sentence:

> He is a ___. He is always complaining about the weather.

Comment: Anyone who lives in New England.

Comment: I was going to say "a Brit," but as a New England native, @Robusto's comment is far more apt.

Comment: Me, I call them “a person who is very fussy about weather”; why would there be a special word for this outside of a Scrabble game or a crossword puzzle?

Comment: Sidebar: I once knew someone who grew morbidly depressed in the summer/winter and was diagnosed with "Seasonal Affective Disorder."

Comment: @Robusto I disagree, Boston is lovely today!

Comment: @APrejean: I think if someone is "depressed in the Summer/Winter" they are just "depressed" ;)

Comment: @Arkamis: Whilst us "Brits" might like to "talk about the weather", we don't necessarily complain about it. "Old people" on the other hand do little else but complain about it!

Comment: @w3d I did say "Sidebar". =/

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: @w3d, SAD is a recognized emotional disorder, a subset of depression. It is most frequently triggered by lack of sunlight during winter months, but _can_ also be triggered by extended daylight during summer months. Either way, it appears to be a disruption to the brain's circadian rhythms.

Answer (score 5):

There is the slang/pejorative term  **weather whiner**. Here is a definition and an example from *[Urbandictionary](https://urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=weather%20whiner)*:

> People who will whine about the weather.
>
> *Weather Whiners are Unvigorous and negative when they whine about the weather. too hot too cold its raining its snowing its sunny don't matter what they aint happy*...

Here, the term *weather whiner* was used for New Yorkers (where the author includes himself) in an article from *[The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2002/04/07/nyregion/soapbox-weather-whiners.html)*:

> But today, as we face a water shortage and, since March 26, a drought emergency, it is clear that we are not cut from the same hearty stock as our forebears. We are **weather whiners**. Maybe we've been spoiled by a string of relatively mild winters. Or maybe we're just never satisfied.

---

On a more serious note, this is a characteristic of a **chronic complainer.** They usually complain about everything including the weather.

An example from [psychologytoday](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-squeaky-wheel/201107/how-deal-chronic-complainers):

> **Optimists see:** A glass half full.
>
> **Pessimists see:** A glass half empty.
>
> **Chronic complainers see:** A glass that is slightly chipped holding water that isn't cold enough, probably because it's tap water when I asked for bottled water and wait, there's a smudge on the rim, too, which means the glass wasn't cleaned properly and now I'll probably end up with some kind of virus. Why do these things always happen to me?!

Comment: "Everybody talks about the weather, but nobody does anything about it."

Comment: psychology-today hiring serious comedians it seems. That was hilarious.

Comment: ...and an **engineer** sees the glass as twice as large as it needs to be!

Answer (score 3):

Consider “**fusspot**”.

It's not specific to fussiness about weather, but is a noun that describes a fussy person. You could make it specific with something like:

> John never likes to go on picnics. He's such a **fusspot** about the weather.

Answer (score 2):

To the definitions already mentioned, I'd like to add a less common one, **meteoropathic**.

Some of us may feel tired when weather changes but still can’t sleep, we get nervous when winds become strong, or we may feel the blues when it rains. If you happened to feel that way than you are suffering from meteoropathy and you are as the like to call it, **a meteoropathic person.** **According to the recent research the number of people who feel the effects of weather changes is growing. And with them the interest for meteoropathy.**

[meteoropathy](http://jubave.com/2007/11/08/what-is-meteoropathy/)

Comment: That was useful.

Comment: This word is used for the people who are affected by the weather or weather changes. It is not that they complain about it but their mood may change.

Comment: Is it 'meteorophatic' or 'meteoropathic'? Your use of 'meteoropathy' militates for the latter, but you use both spellings in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about a **weather snob**?

I've heard people described as "____ snob" when they are particularly picky about something. The specific example I'm thinking of is "beer snob" - someone who only drinks "quality" beers

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[**chronic complainer**](http://m.wikihow.com/Handle-Chronic-Complainers)."

Comment: I gave this as an answer already before you.

Comment: @ermanen That is most likely due to a time lag of some sort. I saw your post being edited after mine. But, when I checked back on the question, your answer indeed appeared a couple minutes before mine.

Comment: It happens. Just reminding. I edited my answer to add "weather whiner".

Comment: @ermanen As you said, it happens. I was working on my answer when your first post was edited.

Answer (score 0):

In the most intense form, **weather-bound**.

> delayed or shut in by bad weather

I would probably sarcastically call them **cold-blooded**.